# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue in react and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have used axios in reactjs component file, but while I want to test these code in browser, show this error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.227.134.91:7000/api/v1/auth/login/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)"
BUT I added 'Access-Control-Origin': '*', to my code. My code is here:
var resultElement=document.getElementById('postresult1');

```
var tel=document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value;
        resultElement.innerHTML='';
        axios.post('http://192.227.134.91:7000/api/v1/auth/login/', 
        JSON.stringify({'mobile_no': tel}),
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
                }}
    )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.statusText);
            var st='OK';
            if(response.statusText == st)
            {
                this.setState({
                    showBaseModal: false,
                    codemodal: true
                });

            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            resultElement.innerHTML='It not exist...';
        });
    mobileNumber is an input in my form.
```

please help me.....
I add a extension to chrome browser, it solved but in another browser like firefox have this error yet.
What do I do? please help me.....
thanks

Comment: Your api endpoint needs to add a rule to accept all requests. Nothing you can do on the front-end.

Comment: which server side language you use?

Comment: it's not frontend side issue

Comment: I have used Django python

Comment: you need cros header in your api, https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: but it work correctly in android app. how can I correct code?

Comment: set express middleware as described in link

Comment: you use express for api alright?